# Formula for the number of cycles of a given length in the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions

Let $C(m,n;k)$ denote the number of cycles of length $k$ in the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$. Obtain a closed formula for the generating series $$\sum_{m,n,k\geq 0}C(m,n;k)\frac{x^my^nz^k}{m!n!}.$$

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: I believe the way to go is similar to counting cycles of length $k$ in $K_n$. There you use the fact that the species of graphs isomorphic to a cycle on $n$ vertices has exponential generating function $J(y;z)=\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{(n-1)!}{2}z^n\frac{y^n}{n!}=\tfrac{1}{2}\log(1-zy)^{-1}-\tfrac{zy}{2}-\left(\tfrac{zy}{2}\right)^2$, then the generating function for graphs with $k$ cycles is the product of the generating functions $\exp(z)$ with $J(y;z)$. But in this case we have $K_{m,n}$ so we need add a partition on the vertices and understand how this affects the species of cycles.